# socket error when using SOCK_RAW and how to accept multiple client with layer 2 communication

Tags: c, network-programming

1. soc = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)); in client side, when run, get == -1 error
2. if accept function can only use with UDP and TCP higher protocol, how to accept multiple client with layer 2 communication?

where can find the code of accept function, i would like to rewrite it for layer 2.

**Updated :**
After tried soc = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
also == -1 , get this error

server side and client side both are the same computer, local one
strange is that running server side, it do not have this error, but running client program got error

```
//#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/nameser.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
//#include "sock.h"

#define MAX_MESSAGE          21000
#define FD_NUM 5
#define tcp_port                5009


//#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
//#include <winsock2.h>

char host_ip[16] = "127.0.0.1";

void task()
{
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    int opt;
    int soc;

    //soc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    soc = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (soc==-1) {
        printf("socket error\n");
    }
    // determine ethernet number    
    /*
    struct ifreq ifr;
    size_t if_name_len=strlen(if_name);
    if (if_name_len<sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)) {
        memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,if_name,if_name_len);
        ifr.ifr_name[if_name_len]=0;
    } else {
        printf("interface name is too long");
    }
    if (ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr)==-1) {
        printf("determine ethernet number error\n");
    }
    int ifindex=ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    */
    // mac address
    /*target address*/
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;

    /*buffer for ethernet frame*/
    void* buffer = (void*)malloc(ETH_FRAME_LEN);

    /*pointer to ethenet header*/
    unsigned char* etherhead = (unsigned char*)buffer;

    /*userdata in ethernet frame*/
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)buffer + 14;

    /*another pointer to ethernet header*/
    struct ethhdr *eh = (struct ethhdr *)etherhead;

    int send_result = 0;

    /*our MAC address*/
    //10:78:d2:ad:90:cb
    //0x10,0x78,0xD2,0xAD,0x90,0xCB
    unsigned char src_mac[6] = {0x10,0x78,0xD2,0xAD,0x90,0xCB};

    /*other host MAC address*/
    unsigned char dest_mac[6] = {0x10,0x78,0xD2,0xAD,0x90,0xCB};

    /*prepare sockaddr_ll*/

    /*RAW communication*/
    socket_address.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;    
    /*we don't use a protocoll above ethernet layer
      ->just use anything here*/
    socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);  

    /*index of the network device
    see full code later how to retrieve it*/
    socket_address.sll_ifindex  = 0;

    /*ARP hardware identifier is ethernet*/
    socket_address.sll_hatype   = ARPHRD_ETHER;

    /*target is another host*/
    socket_address.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_OTHERHOST;

    /*address length*/
    socket_address.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;     
    /*MAC - begin*/
    socket_address.sll_addr[0]  = 0x10;     
    socket_address.sll_addr[1]  = 0x78;     
    socket_address.sll_addr[2]  = 0xD2;
    socket_address.sll_addr[3]  = 0xAD;
    socket_address.sll_addr[4]  = 0x90;
    socket_address.sll_addr[5]  = 0xCB;
    /*MAC - end*/
    socket_address.sll_addr[6]  = 0x00;/*not used*/
    socket_address.sll_addr[7]  = 0x00;/*not used*/

    memcpy((void*)buffer, (void*)dest_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy((void*)(buffer+ETH_ALEN), (void*)src_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    eh->h_proto = 0x00;

    int j = 0;
    for (j = 46; --j; data[j] = (unsigned char)((int) (255.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0))));

    /*
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int len = sizeof(server);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(5008);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(host_ip);

    int CONN_SOCK   = InitSocketTcp(tcp_port);
    if(connect(CONN_SOCK, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
    {
        printf("connection failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("connection ok!\n");
    }
    */
    while(1)
    {
        char buff[492] = "\0";
        printf("input: ");
        scanf("%s", buff);

        //send(CONN_SOCK,buff,strlen(buff),0);
        /*send the packet*/
        send_result = sendto(soc, buff, ETH_FRAME_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
        send_result == -1?printf("send error"):0;

        if(buff[0] == 'q')
        {
            //shutdown(CONN_SOCK, SD_SEND);
            //closesocket(CONN_SOCK);
            //WSACleanup();
            close(soc);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //for(int i=10; i!=0; --i)
        //pthread_create();
    task();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `accept` when using raw sockets. `accept` only works when using UDP, TCP or other higher level protocols.

Comment: i find accept can be compiled success when use with sockaddr_ll

Comment: Why are you using raw sockets? TCP/UDP should be a lot easier to use.

Comment: because i want to test how faster layer 2 than tcp/udp

Comment: When `socket` returns an error, you can check the variable `errno` (might have to include `<errno.h>`) what it is. To get a printable string from `errno` use the function `strerror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept() is only used for TCP or UDP (practically it's main use is in tcp), because it establishes a connection. A connection does 3 way handshake in case of tcp and exchanges information such as sequence numbers etc. and is completely identified by a socket (port plus ip address)

In contrast to that you can simply use sendto and receivefrom api's as normally used in case of udp, where each packet may follow a different path to reach destination. You do not require an accept in case of udp communication. The same can be extended to link layer (L2) frames i.e. each side can send or receive at will without actually establishing a connection first.

This should be done using root

Comment: It is not true that they follow the same path. They just need to get from A to B. TCP does not have/use a specified path. Each IP packet makes its own way and possibly does not make it.

Comment: what happen when two connection receive at the same time?

Comment: @EdHeal In case of tcp, there always is a virtual circuit which means a dedicated path established. A connection is broken if that path is not followed and need to be established again. Please read Richard Stevens or quote an authentic reference if you believe that is not the case. TCP provides reliability on TOP of IP by trying to do retransmissions if earlier packets did not reach the other end. The difference in routing between tcp vs udp packets is, that udp packets choose route on each intermediate node where as tcp packets don't.

Comment: http://nrg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mptcp/ and besides TCP is built upon IP. IP is connectionless and therefore a packet is free to travel in whatever route it desires (or to be accurate the network). Also TCP does include in the header a number to reorder the packets when they are out of sequence. See the RFC

Comment: i know connectionless, but do not know what does it mean. What are the disadvantage of using layer 2 communication

Comment: It means the same socket is being used for followed up communication. Also as opposed to "connected" there are several things not present such as sequence number exchanged in the initial 3 way handshake, packet reordering information etc. Connectionless treats each packet uniquely and picks entire info for sending it every time.

Comment: @Jo0o0 have you tried using PF_PACKET instead assuming you are on Linux?

Comment: @fayyazkl - Please read RFC793. The routers do not care if it is TCP/UDP. To them they are just IP packets. So too there knowledge they need to get to B. They can have multiple routes to choose from. They do load balancing and hence two TCP packets might have different routes. Hence may come out of sequence but the sequence numbers will enable the receiver to reorder them.

Comment: @Jo0o0 i suspect there is some thing else causing the error. Please post your code.

Comment: @fayyazkl There are no virtual circuits in TCP, by design. For example, it was established many years ago that most Internet connections use a different return path from the forward path. The Internet is free to route any individual packet any way it likes.

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for clearing that up. It was a misconception at my end

Comment: @fayyazkl - You are welcome - we just learn from each other at the end of the day.

Comment: @Jo0o0 This might help "Only processes with effective UID 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability may open packet socket" http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man7/packet.7.html